# How to I prevent content from scrolling behind footer of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

Been struggling with this problem for awhile now :\ Let me explain ... First here is a picture of the UITableViewController that is giving me problems:

[image]

The UITableViewController has 3 dynamic cells

1. the header - everything above green line
2. main cells - everything b/w green and red lines
3. the footer cell - below red line

I have no problem with the header, and repeating cell. My issue is with the footer cell...womp womp.  When I scroll on the main content - (i.e. the area between the green and red line) the content hides behind the footer.

Here is an image of when I am scrolling - notice the bottom two links (About BVB and Settings have disappeared)
[image]

Lastly here is my footer function:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  footerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuFooterCell") as! MenuFooterViewCell
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerCell
    return footerCell
}
```

**So What Can I do to fix this ??**
Really appreciate the help in advance :) If you give me a good answer, I will definitely mark it as correct! -Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have the cells hide behind the footer:
Make your FooterView another cell in your tableView.

Else:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

Comment: commented out this line: self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerCell  and added this line: self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero) but it didn't work  :\. Thanks for the try though!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough the first time through. Why are you using a Footer Cell? The purpose of the footer cell is to remain there and act the way it is now. If you don't want it, then don't add it to the table view. The code that I shared should then go in the viewDidLoad function of your ViewController.

Comment: Sorry the reason I have the footer cell there is because it will be for an ad banner. I suppose I could just eliminate the footer, add another dynamic cell (which will house the ad banner.) Does this seem fair game - to add an ad banner into a table cell ?

Comment: Do you want the menu options to hide behind the add banner? If so, then leave it how it was. If you don't want them to hide behind the banner, then the ad has to be a table cell.

Comment: I don't like the hiding period. It looks very tacky. I will make the ad a table cell. Thanks for helping me work through this :)

Comment: Technically the answer you give isn't the right one, if you edit the one above I can mark it correct!

Comment: Edited. Glad I could help.